# How Select Random with parent_id in mysql?

Tags: mysql, random, subquery

I have table like this...

```
╔═════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ id  ║  text  ║  parent_id  ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║   1 ║  test  ║           1 ║
║   2 ║  asd   ║           1 ║
║   3 ║  dsa   ║           1 ║
║   4 ║  fgh   ║           4 ║
║   5 ║  jkl   ║           4 ║
║   6 ║  kkk   ║           4 ║
║   7 ║  asas  ║           7 ║
╚═════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

how to get random output like :

```
╔═════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ id  ║  text  ║  parent_id  ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║   4 ║  fgh   ║           4 ║
║   5 ║  jkl   ║           4 ║
║   6 ║  kkk   ║           4 ║
║   7 ║  asas  ║           7 ║
║   1 ║  test  ║           1 ║
║   2 ║  asd   ║           1 ║
║   3 ║  dsa   ║           1 ║
╚═════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

or

```
╔═════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ id  ║  text  ║  parent_id  ║
╠═════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║   7 ║  asas  ║           7 ║
║   4 ║  fgh   ║           4 ║
║   5 ║  jkl   ║           4 ║
║   6 ║  kkk   ║           4 ║
║   1 ║  test  ║           1 ║
║   2 ║  asd   ║           1 ║
║   3 ║  dsa   ║           1 ║
╚═════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

and etc....

Comment: next time try http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to create nice looking tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a subquery, similar to Juan solution:

```
SELECT s.* FROM YourTable s
INNER JOIN (select parent_id,max(rand()) as randVal FROM YourTable GROUP BY parent_id) t
 ON(s.parent_id = t.parent_id)
ORDER BY t.randVal
```

Comment: `ORDER BY t.randVal, s.id` is needed.

Comment: Actually no, its not @dylansu

Comment: the order in group may not be in ASC any more.

Comment: Ok, and? I don't understand the problem. Each group will get a random order id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY parent_id * rand()
```

Comment: This will produce the same rand value for each group of parent id?

Comment: @sagi  I dont think so. I test it on postgres and generate very randomly order. I want double check on mysql but sqlFiddle is down.

Comment: But he needs it to produce the same value for each parent id.. not totaly random.

Comment: Ohh I didnt saw that. :(

Comment: @Megandi You could explain it better, Just looking I tought was all random values. I will fix it. But  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry have to go to a meeting. Is easy to do with a subquery first. I will be back in a couple of hours if no one else solve it.

Comment: I am sorry, i am bad in english.. i am so confused how to explain that.. so i just give the example output.. i'm sorry..

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sorry but I dont agree with you. First this doesnt answer the question because the question wasnt very clear to begin with and want a very different output at the one I tought. Second I cant eleaborate more beside explaining `ORDER BY` and  I wont do that.

Comment: @JuanCarlos - I only said it _may_ answer the question.  It's hard for me (as a non-expert here - I only happened by in Review) to know, particularly without the explanation it clearly needs.  When the question is unclear, it is even more useful than usual to state your interpretation of the question, and how you're addressing it.  If you feel it doesn't answer the question as now clarified by the asker, consider amending or deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly update based on @sagi 's ans, appending guarantee of order of rows in groups.

Here is the demo.

## SQL:

```
-- data
create table tbl(id int, text char(20), parent_id int);
insert into tbl values
(1 , 'test', 1 ),
(2 , 'asd',  1 ),
(3 , 'dsa',  1 ),
(4 , 'fgh',  4 ),
(5 , 'jkl',  4 ),
(6 , 'kkk',  4 ),
(7 , 'asas', 7 );
select * from tbl;

select t.* 
from tbl t inner join 
    (select parent_id, rand() rand_val from tbl group by parent_id) r
    USING(parent_id)
order by rand_val, id;
```

## Output:

```
mysql> select t.*  from tbl t inner join      (select parent_id, rand() rand_val from tbl group by parent_id) r     USING(parent_id) order by rand_val, id;
+------+------+-----------+
| id   | text | parent_id |
+------+------+-----------+
|    7 | asas |         7 |
|    4 | fgh  |         4 |
|    5 | jkl  |         4 |
|    6 | kkk  |         4 |
|    1 | test |         1 |
|    2 | asd  |         1 |
|    3 | dsa  |         1 |
+------+------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select t.*  from tbl t inner join      (select parent_id, rand() rand_val from tbl group by parent_id) r     USING(parent_id) order by rand_val, id;
+------+------+-----------+
| id   | text | parent_id |
+------+------+-----------+
|    4 | fgh  |         4 |
|    5 | jkl  |         4 |
|    6 | kkk  |         4 |
|    1 | test |         1 |
|    2 | asd  |         1 |
|    3 | dsa  |         1 |
|    7 | asas |         7 |
+------+------+-----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```